# Syntax error while installing pdfminer using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer

I want to use the pdfminer for extracting the text info. I have downloaded the pdfminer-20131113. I have installed the python in `C:\python34`.
Now using cmd, I am setting the path to the `setup.py` file of pdfminer.
and running the following command.

```
python setup.py install
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
> D:\pdfminer-20101226>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pdfminer import __version__
  File "D:\pdfminer-20101226\pdfminer\__init__.py", line 4
    if __name__ == '__main__': print __version__
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems to be some error in the setup.py file of pdfminer, which I am not sure how to resolve.

Also, I saw a pdf2txt.py file in the build folder of pdfminer. I tried to use that also as `pdf2txt.py -o output.html pdffilename.pdf` (with full path). but instead of converting it. it opens the `pdf2txt.py` file.

Comment: You forgot to post the error message. Most likely, the code is not Python 3 compatible and requires Python 2 to run instead.

Comment: unrelated: do not use `python setup.py install`. It doesn't allow to uninstall cleanly. Use `pip install ..` instead. `pip` is included with Python 3.4

Comment: there is an attempt to port it to Python 3: [`pdfminer3k`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: When using pip 1.4 or newer you do need add a `>=20131113` version specifier though, see https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/issues/27

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `pdfminer3k` uses the standard `major.minor.bugfix` versions. The brute-force method in general is just add `--pre`: `pip install --pre`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I was talking about the original PDFMiner project, not pdfminer3k. How would one use the `--pre` flag in a `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: requirements.txt should contain fixed versions

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I  certainly agree there; but not everyone views it that way. Playing devils advocate here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [PDFMiner project homepage](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) states:

> Written entirely in Python. (for version 2.4 or newer)

and further down:

> Install Python 2.4 or newer. (**Python 3 is not supported.**)

so you'll have to install Python 2 to run this project.

Alternatively, you could try the [Python 3 port, `pdfminer3k`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k); it hasn't seen any updates in 20 months, while PDFMiner does have more recent releases, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Martijin, can you help me for the pdf2txt.py
I am trying to run pdf2txt.py pdffile.pdf
But it opens the pdf2txt.py

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable

Answer (score 6):

This should solve your problem in Python 3

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

Answer (score 0):

[pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) is a fork with Python 2+3 support using six. Last commit was 15 days ago.